# How to save text after send button is pressed

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have created a custom keyboard using InputMethodService. Now i want to save all the text written by it in my local db after the send button is pressed. How can i achieve that?

Comment: can you able to tell what you have tried for this ?

Comment: What the problem to save text from textView to db?

Comment: @thealeksandr the problem is that this textView belongs to andriod default sms application. and i dont know its id.